# 1999-Mercury Cougar..noisy new suspension bushings

Tags: suspension, mercury, bushing, cougar

I have a 99 mercury cougar I just picked up.
The rear suspension bushings were replaced, but are very noisy.
Is there anything I can do to stop it or do I just have to live with it?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are urethane bushings (likely if they are some color other than black), they need lubrication or they will squeak. Part of the installation process is to lube the bushings prior to assembly. If this wasn't done you can try to get some lube in after the fact. You need to use a lithium based grease. You could use an aerosol type with an application straw. Hopefully some of the lube will flow in the crevasses and quiet them down. Removing the mounting bolts may allow better penetration.

Comment: thank you for your help. the guy I bought the car from has sprayed them with wd40 but didn't seem to help much. he is going to spray them again this week.

Comment: Do not WD-40. As I stated use a lithium based lube. WD-40 will eventually ruin the bushings.